# SharedWorker in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker, shared-worker

I am using web workers in my React application with a helper class that looks like this:

```
export class WebWorker {
constructor(worker) {
    const code = worker.toString();
    const blob = new Blob(["(" + code + ")()"]);
    return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
}}
```

The worker looks something like:

```
export default () => {
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    switch (e.data.event) {
        case 'start':
            // Start back ground task
            break;
        case 'stop':
            // Stop background task
            break;
    }
}, false);
```

Then I am able to create the worker using

```
let sessionWorker = new WebWorker(SessionWorker);
sessionWorker.postMessage({event: "start"})
```

This works fine, however I now need to use a SharedWorker and I am having trouble getting it to work. All of the resources I've found show regular web workers. There is this SO Question [Using Shared Worker in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122388/using-shared-worker-in-react) but it doesn't work for me. It actually looks identical to my regular WebWorker code, but this doesn't work because SharedWorkers require that you implement an onconnect function, and I don't understand how to do that. Non-react examples that I've found show the worker script as:

```
onconnect = function(e) {
   var port = e.ports[0];
   port.onmessage = function(e) {
     var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
     port.postMessage(workerResult);
   }
}
```

but if I put that in my worker js file and follow the same pattern using the WebWorker helper, the worker.toString() just returns [object Window] and it never gets executed. I don't understand how to create an 'onconnect' function that will get called.  I've tried variations like this:

```
import React from 'react';

self.onconnect = (e) => {
    var port = e.ports[0];
    console.log("test log");
    port.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log("Message received ", e)
        port.postMessage("test");
    }
}
export default self;
```

Ultimately nothing works for me. Clearly I do not understand exports at all in Javascript. If I just export a function called onconnect it never gets called, clearly the onconnect has to belong to some sort of class-like context (like Window or Self) but I don't understand what is needed

Thankyou,
Troy.

Comment: Actually it seems that I did get it working eventually but I didn't know it was working because my console log for the shared worker goes to a different log. You need to view the shared worker logs (in Chrome at least) from a url "chrome://inspect/#workers". So my shared workers work, but I have another problem in that the URL.createObjectURL(blob) creates a new URL each time so the shared worker isn't actually shared, it's restarted in each instance.

Comment: I've got this working, but I cannot import modules in my shared worker. If I add { type: 'module'} to my instantiation it fails to load the worker with just the message "Failed to fetch a worker script.". If I do not have the the type: 'module' then I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: cuid__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is not defined" in the worker.